# SAS - Stored process is greyed out

Tags: sas, sas-metadata, sas-stored-process

I am very new to using the SAS Enterprise Guide but have been using older versions of SAS for a while. I also work a little in Javascript. Until today I was not aware these can be combined. I am trying to follow this tutorial.

[Interactive Charts and Graphs using SAS Stored Process and JavaScript libraries](https://assemredouan.wordpress.com/tag/charts-and-graphs-using-javascript-libraries-and-sas/)

The first step is to create a stored process but mine is greyed out and I cannot find any information about this online.

Thank you so much for your help!!

[image: Why is stored process greyed out?]

Comment: Are you working on a SAS server or a single install? There's an update to this blog posted on communities.sas.com that doesn't require stored processes.

Comment: There must be a SAS Stored Process Server running with your SAS Server. It is the same like no OLAP Cubes without SAS OLAP Server.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Guide is only needed to register your Stored Process (be sure to allow global macro variables).  You may have this capability disabled.  Alternative approaches are to use SAS Management Console, or even SAS code to register your Stored Process (see this [example](https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/meta/mm_createstp.sas)).

FWIW, javascript and SAS work incredibly well together!  To save yourself a ton of effort I'd advise using the (free) SASjs [data adapter](https://github.com/macropeople/sasjs).  More info here:  https://sasjs.io